# How to add a custom extension when using typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tiptap

I am trying to add a custom extension to scrumpy/tiptap, but my project is using typescript and I think this is causing me some problems.

I got the code from [this issue](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/issues/561), and tried importing and using it like this:

```
import HighlightMark from '../ts/tiptap-extensions/HighlightMark';

...

this.editor = new Editor({
  content: '<p>This is just a boring paragraph.</p>',
  extensions: [new HighlightMark()]
})
```

But I am faced with this error

> Type 'HighlightMark' is not assignable to type 'ExtensionOption'.
>     Type 'HighlightMark' is not assignable to type 'Mark'.
>       The types returned by 'schema.toDOM(...)' are incompatible between these types.
>         Type '(string | number | { style: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'DOMOutputSpec'.
>           Property '0' is missing in type '(string | number | { style: string; })[]' but required in type 'DOMOutputSpecArray'.

---

I tried importing it in a .d.ts (as I had to do with all the built-int tiptap extensions), but I get an error telling me that I can't import files from relative path here:

> Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.ts(2439)

---

I also tried just changing the file to typescript (`HighlightMark.ts`), but it then gives me several errors:

> Property 'commands' in type 'HighlightMark' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Mark'.
>     Type '({ type }: { type: any; }) => (attrs: any) => Command' is not assignable to type '({ type, schema, attrs }: { type: MarkType; schema: MarkSpec; attrs: { [key: string]: string; }; }) => CommandGetter'.
>       Type '(attrs: any) => Command' is not assignable to type 'CommandGetter'.

and

> 'mark' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
>   Parameter 'mark' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

and

> Parameter 'attrs' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

**Has anyone done this before? Is it actually possible?**

This is the code from HighlightMark.js:

```
   import { Mark } from 'tiptap';
   import { toggleMark } from 'tiptap-commands'

  export default class HighlightMark extends Mark {
  get name() {
    return "mark";
  }

  get schema() {
    return {
      attrs: {
        color: {
          default: "rgba(240,87,100,0.7)"
        }
      },
      parseDOM: [
        {
          tag: "mark"
        }
      ],
      toDOM: mark => [
        "mark",
        {
          style: `background: red` // ${mark.attrs.color}
        },
        0
      ]
    };
  }

  commands({ type }) {
    return attrs => toggleMark(type, attrs);
  }
}
```

Comment: Bassie could u try using `as` keyword? `(new HighlightMark() as ExtensionOption)`;

Comment: @SankalpBhamare Thanks for your advice Sankalp, it seems to work when casting `as any` - but of course that isn't a great solution!

Comment: Well I just hate these things about typescript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I could resolve this by initialising tiptap like this

```
this.editor = new Editor({
  content: '<p>This is just a boring paragraph.</p>',
  extensions: [new HighlightMark() as any]
```

Which is not ideal, but seems to be working for now.

If anyone can post the real solution I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by returning an object from `toDOM` rather than an array, like so:

```js
toDOM: mark => {
  return {
    0: 'mark',
    1: {
      style: `background:${mark.attrs.color}`
    },
    2: '0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run into the same problem as you, but what worked for me may be of help. To get this to work for me, I had to export the class as a module from my .js file. For you, it would look like this:

HighlightMark.js

```js
import { Mark } from 'tiptap';
import { toggleMark } from 'tiptap-commands'

...

export { HighlightMark };
```

and then in your main ts file

```
import highlightMark from '../ts/tiptap-extensions/HighlightMark';

...

this.editor = new Editor({
  content: '<p>This is just a boring paragraph.</p>',
  extensions: [ new HighlightMark() ]
})
```